# mysql select statement to retirve single row with the highest date from every month

Tags: mysql

Example:

Columns:

```
id, date(mysql date), other fields....
```

Rows:

```
1, 2011-01-11
2, 2011-31-10
3, 2011-30-10
4, 2011-25-09
5, 2011-25-09
6, 2011-25-09
7, 2011-21-09
```

Mysql select statement to select the last date of every month in given rows... not just unique... if in a month the last date has more than 1 row then need to retrive all rows of that last date.

Considering the above example select statement should give the following result set

```
1, 2011-01-11
2, 2011-31-10
4, 2011-25-09
5, 2011-25-09
6, 2011-25-09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the right rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date_col IN (
  SELECT MAX(date_col) 
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY MONTH(date_col)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spec is conflicting. Nonetheless, the following query will retrieve all rows that have the highest date for a month.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date = 
  (SELECT MAX(date) FROM your_table 
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m'), date_column))
```